# Handling imprecise timing when testing cancellation of paged query

Tags: go, concurrency

I have an object I'm using to make paged SQL queries that allows for the queries to be run asynchronously:

```
type PagedQuery[T any] struct {
    Results   chan []*T
    Errors    chan error
    Done      chan error
    Quit      chan error
    client    *sql.DB
}

func NewPagedQuery[T any](client *sql.DB) *PagedQuery[T] {
    return &PagedQuery[T]{
        Results:   make(chan []*T, 1),
        Errors:    make(chan error, 1),
        Done:      make(chan error, 1),
        Quit:      make(chan error, 1),
        client:    client,
    }
}

func (paged *PagedQuery[T]) requestAsync(ctx context.Context, queries ...*Query) {

    conn, err := client.Conn(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        paged.Errors <- err
        return
    }

    defer func() {
        conn.Close()
        paged.Done <- nil
    }()

    for i, query := range queries {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case <-paged.Quit:
            return
        default:
        }

        rows, err := conn.QueryContext(ctx, query.String, query.Arguments...)
        if err != nil {
            paged.Errors <- err
            return
        }

        data, err := sql.ReadRows[T](rows)
        if err != nil {
            paged.Errors <- err
            return
        }

        paged.Results <- data
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test this code, specifically the cancellation part. My test code looks like this:

```
svc, mock := createServiceMock("TEST_DATABASE", "TEST_SCHEMA")

mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta("TEST QUERY")).
    WithArgs(...).
    WillReturnRows(mock.NewRows([]string{"t", "v", "o", "c", "h", "l", "vw", "n"}))

ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
go svc.requestAsync(ctx, query1, query2, query3, query4)

time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
cancel()

results := make([]data, 0)
loop:
for {
    select {
    case <-query.Done:
        break loop
    case err := <-query.Errors:
        Expect(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
    case r := <-query.Results:
        results = append(results, r...)
    }
}

Expect(results).Should(BeEmpty())
Expect(mock.ExpectationsWereMet()).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred()) // fails here
```

The issue I'm running into is that this test fails occaisionally at the line indicated by my comment, because when `cancel()` is called, execution isn't guaranteed to be at the `switch` statement where I check for `<-ctx.Done` or `<-Quit`. Execution could be anywhere in the loop up to where I send the results to the `Results` channel. Except that doesn't make sense because execution should block until I receive data from the `Results` channel, which I don't do until after I call `cancel()`. Furthermore, I'm relying on the [sqlmock](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) package for SQL testing which doesn't allow for any sort of fuzzy checking where SQL queries are concerned. Why am I getting this failure and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was the result of my own lack of understanding around Go channels. I assumed that, by creating a `chan([]*T, 1)` meant that the channel would block when it was full (i.e. when it contained a single item) but that is not the case. Rather, the block occurs when I attempted to send to the channel when its buffer was full. So, by modifying `Results` like this:

```
func NewPagedQuery[T any](client *sql.DB) *PagedQuery[T] {
    return &PagedQuery[T]{
        Results:   make(chan []*T),    // Remove buffer here
        Errors:    make(chan error, 1),
        Done:      make(chan error, 1),
        Quit:      make(chan error, 1),
        client:    client,
    }
}
```

I can ensure that the channel blocks until the data it contains is received. This one change fixed all the problems with testing.